# Are There Universal Entailments Under the Rieger-Nishimura Lattice for Conditionals When the Antecedent is Higher on It?

Tags: model-theory, lattice-orders, intuitionistic-logic

I'm working on a bottom-up (atomics-to-proposition) intuitionistic decision procedure, and I encountered some fruits with the Rieger-Nishimura lattice. Specifically, I am looking at [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2209.03920.pdf) from Kocsis, which constructs the RN lattice as follows:

- $d_0 = i_0 = \bot$
- $d_1 = A$
- $i_1 = \neg A$
- $d_{n+1} = d_n \vee i_n$
- $i_{n+1} = i_n \rightarrow d_n$
- $d_\infty = i_\infty = \top$

So, $\neg\neg A$ is $i_2$, for example, and the LEM is $d_2$.

The article also cites these entailments:

1. $d_n \rightarrow d_m = \top$ when $n \leq m$,
2. $d_n \rightarrow i_m = \top$ when $n=0$ or $n<m$,
3. $i_n \rightarrow d_m = \top$ when $n=0$ or $n<m$, and
4. $i_n \rightarrow i_m = \top$ when $n=0$, $n=m$, or $n+1<m$.

My question is, are there guaranteed outputs for cases when the opposite is the case for $n$ and $m$ above?

For $d_n \rightarrow d_m$ and $n>m$, I was able to find equivalent solutions:

- When $m=0$, $d_n \rightarrow d_m = \neg d_n$ (which is $\bot$ when $n>1$ and $i_1$ when $n=1$)
- When $m>0$ and $n-m=1$, $d_n \rightarrow d_m = i_n$
- When $m>0$ and $n-m>1$, $d_n \rightarrow d_m = d_m$

The basic idea in that case was to exploit that $d$ is disjunctive, so $d_n \rightarrow d_m$ is always

- $d_n = d_1 \vee i_1 \dots \vee i_{n-1}$
- $d_m = d_1 \vee i_1 \dots \vee i_{m-1}$

Since $(A \vee B) \rightarrow C$ iff $(A \rightarrow C) \wedge (B \rightarrow C)$ is an intuitionistic theorem,

$(d_1 \vee i_1 \dots \vee i_{n-1}) \rightarrow d_m$ cancels out redundancies from the $\vee$-$I$ theorem as...

- $⊤ \wedge \dots \wedge (i_m \rightarrow d_m) \wedge \dots \wedge (i_{n-1} \rightarrow d_m)$

and yield the above results, depending on the distance of $n$ from $m$.

I didn't see any straightforward way to do this with the remaining combinations of $d$ and $i$ after negating the condition from before. Can this be done? If so, how?

For clarification, the remaining questions are those of entailment for...

- $d_n \rightarrow i_m$ when $n > 0$ and $n \geq m$;
- $i_n \rightarrow d_m$ when $n > 0$ and $n \geq m$; and
- $i_n \rightarrow i_m$ when $n > 0$, $n \neq m$, and $n+1 \geq m$.

Comment: **1.** I converted your question to MathJax, please see the [MathJax tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/645935). **2.** Is your query *can we do the remaining combinations of $d$ and $i$ using the specific condition you derived*, or simply *what are the remaining combinations $d_n \vee/\rightarrow i_m$ equal to?* **3.** For simplicity, can you list the remaining cases explicitly? I'm in a good position to help (as the author of the cited article) but being able to find the missing cases in one place would make my life simpler and reduce my "activation energy" :)

Comment: Absolutely, and thank you.

Comment: @Z.A.K. , I've added the missing cases to the bottom of the post. My suspicion is that, with just the conditional operator figured out to have single decidable outputs, I can get that much closer to working out disjunction. Conjunction and negation were relatively trivial to work out.

Comment: Sweet, thanks. Looks like Alex wrote up the results of the missing cases in the meantime. I'll try to double-check that and write up proofs from the order axioms later today, but there might be delays (my workday has just started, and it's looking more intense than expected).

Comment: Comment: I do plan to write derivations eventually, but got delayed. The tables provided by Alex Kruckman below should let you proceed with your project in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give a full definition / case analysis for the operations $\vee$, and $\rightarrow$ and $\wedge$ on the Rieger-Nishimura latice below. I do this for four reasons:

1. Alex's otherwise excellent answer contains a few minor mistakes at the time of writing, so I want to write down something whose correctness I've checked.
2. I'd like to put the full operation tables here for future reference.
3. I have immediate need for these tables to answer another question on this website.
4. I prefer a presentation where different cases are not merged even if they yield the same result, and overlapping cases are guaranteed to give the same result: it makes the structure easier to see, and correctness easier to ascertain.

Keep in mind that the four cases I give in the article linked above do determine the order of the Rieger-Nishimura lattice completely. Consequently, one could deduce all of these equalities from those four. However, this boils down to giving a proof of Nishimura's theorem, and takes a significant amount of work, which I can't invest right now: I might come back to this answer at some point, and expand it into a proof.

In what follows, $x$ denotes one of $\top, d_n, i_n$, and the notations $d_n$ and $i_n$ have $n < \infty$: to keep things simple, we always treat the cases $\top=d_\infty=i_\infty$ separately.

**Disjunction $\vee$**

- $\top \vee x = \top = x \vee \top$
- $d_n \vee d_m = \begin{cases}
  d_m & \text{if } n < m\\
  d_m & \text{if } n = m\\
  d_n & \text{if } n > m
  \end{cases}$
- $d_n \vee i_m = \begin{cases}
  d_n & \text{if } m = 0\\
  i_m & \text{if } n < m\\
  d_{n+1} & \text{if } n = m, m > 0\\
  d_n & \text{if } n > m
  \end{cases}$
- $i_n \vee d_m = d_m \vee i_n$
- $i_n \vee i_m = \begin{cases}
  i_n & \text{if } m = 0\\
  i_n & \text{if } n = 0\\
  i_m & \text{if } n + 1 < m, n > 0\\
  d_{m+1} & \text{if } n + 1 = m, n > 0\\
  i_m & \text{if } n = m, n > 0, m > 0\\
  d_{n+1} & \text{if } n = m + 1, m > 0\\
  i_n & \text{if } n > m + 1
  \end{cases}$

**Implication $\rightarrow$**

- $\top \rightarrow x = x$
- $x \rightarrow \top = \top$
- $d_n \rightarrow d_m = \begin{cases} 
  \top & \text{if } n < m\\
  \top & \text{if } n = m\\
  i_{m+1} & \text{if } n = m + 1\\
  d_m & \text{if } n > m + 1
  \end{cases}$
- $d_n \rightarrow i_m = \begin{cases} 
  d_n \rightarrow d_0 & \text{if } m = 0\\
  \top & \text{if } n < m\\
  i_m & \text{if } n = m, m > 0\\
  i_m & \text{if } n > m, m > 0
  \end{cases}$
- $i_n \rightarrow d_m = \begin{cases}
  \top & \text{if } n = 0\\
  \top & \text{if } n < m\\
  i_{n+1} & \text{if } n = m, n > 0\\
  i_{n+1} & \text{if } n = m + 1\\
  i_{m+1} & \text{if } n = m + 2\\
  d_m & \text{if } n > m + 2
  \end{cases}$
- $i_n \rightarrow i_m = \begin{cases}
  i_n \rightarrow d_0 & \text{if } m = 0\\ 
  \top & \text{if } n = 0\\
  \top & \text{if } n + 1 < m\\
  i_m & \text{if } n + 1 = m, n > 0\\
  \top & \text{if } n = m\\
  i_m & \text{if } n > m, m > 0
  \end{cases}$

**Conjunction $\wedge$**

- $\top \wedge x = x = x \wedge \top$
- $d_n \wedge d_m = \begin{cases} 
  d_n & \text{if } n < m\\
  d_m & \text{if } n = m\\
  d_m & \text{if } n > m
  \end{cases}$
- $d_n \wedge i_m = \begin{cases} 
  d_n & \text{if } n < m\\
  d_0 & \text{if } n = m = 0\\
  d_{n-1} & \text{if } n = m, n > 0\\
  i_m & \text{if } n > m
  \end{cases}$
- $i_n \wedge d_m = d_m \wedge i_n$
- $i_n \wedge i_m = \begin{cases} 
  i_n & \text{if } n + 1 < m\\
  i_m & \text{if } n > m + 1\\
  i_m & \text{if } n = m\\
  d_0 & \text{if } m = 0\text{ or } n = 0\\
  d_{m-1} & \text{if } n = m + 1, m > 0\\
  d_{n-1} & \text{if } n + 1 = m, n > 0
  \end{cases}$

One can derive megation using the identity $\neg x = x \rightarrow d_0$: the resulting table is also given in the comments.

Comment: I'll triple-check these against what I've got. I also built one for negation, but it's just this: $\neg \bot ⊨ \top$, $\neg d_1 ⊨ i_1$, $\neg i_2 ⊨ i_1$, $\neg d_1 ⊨ i_1$, $\neg x_n ⊨ \bot$ when $n > 2$, and $\neg d_n ⊨ \bot$ when $n > 1$.

Comment: Also, while minor for an edit, the $d_n \rightarrow d_m$ output is currently $d$, but should be $d_m$. The site wouldn't let me edit it unless it was at least six characters worth of editing.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I incorporated the fix, and signposted negation a bit more.

Comment: My turn! :) Your tables also have at least one issue in the $i_0$ cases. $d_0\vee i_0= \bot\vee\bot =\bot$, but your table says it should be $d_1$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Well spotted, there were issues here: you pointed out $d_0 \vee i_0$, but I also had the same issue in $i_1 \vee i_0$. This is because in my original draft, I excluded $i_0$ just as I exclude $\top$. Fixed it up in the current edit (hopefully without introducing any new issues).

Comment: I noticed this small discrepancy in the original paper, so I just clarified the rules as, for instance, $d_{n+1} = d_n \vee i_n$ when $n > 0$. Then, I handled the $\top$ and $\bot$ operands independently, since their operations are classical fare and were going to be more frequent for my use case. [I also updated the Gist with a table layout.](https://gist.github.com/hebozhe/2e2ceda420b4bc7f3bd68584137779b3), though it won't be of much use for my intended purpose.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, I believe the remaining cases are:

\begin{align*}
d_n\to d_m &= \begin{cases} 
\top & \text{if }n\leq m\\
i_{m+1} & \text{if }n = m+1\\
d_m & \text{if }n > m+1
\end{cases}\\
\\
i_n\to i_m &= \begin{cases} 
\top & \text{if }n=0, n=m, \text{or }n<m-1\\
i_{m} & \text{if }0\neq n = m-1, \text{or }n>m
\end{cases}\\
\\
d_n\to i_m &= \begin{cases} 
\top & \text{if }n<m\text{ or }n=0\\
i_{m} & \text{if }0\neq n \geq m
\end{cases}\\
i_n\to d_m &= \begin{cases} 
\top & \text{if }n<m\text{ or }n=0\\
i_{m+1} & \text{if }0\neq n = m \text{ or }n = m+2\\
i_{m+2} & \text{if }n=m+1\\
d_m & \text{if }n > m+2.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

You can read all of these off directly from the structure of the Rieger-Nishimura lattice, using the fact that $x\to y$ is the greatest element $z$ such that $z\land x \leq y$. Of course, for this you have to take for granted that you understand the structure of the lattice. A proof directly from the definitions of $d_n$ and $i_n$ would take more work.

Comment: Good idea just consulting the lattice. From that, I managed some tables that I put into a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/hebozhe/2e2ceda420b4bc7f3bd68584137779b3). I'll need to double-check them to see if they're correct and exact (i.e., there's no better node selection for certain combinations and positions of propositions on it).

Comment: I think I can see a few minor issues in the cases above: e.g. I believe $d_1 \rightarrow i_0$ should result in $i_1$, but the above equation suggest it evaluates to $i_0 = \bot$ instead; similarly for $i_1 \rightarrow i_0$, which should evaluate to $i_2$. But yeah, the right way to derive these is to think carefully about the lattice.

Comment: Speaking of, I totally cheated my way through negation. I just know that $\neg \neg \neg A \leftrightarrow \neg A$, did the remaining entailments for the reducible literals $d_1$, $i_1$, and $i_2$, and then found out the lowest node where a classical tautology would be negated to have them entail $\bot$.